# Discord music bot - error with ffpmeg player and embed message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to create a music bot for Discord in Python with queue, but every time I run, an error pops up. Can someone please tell me, what is wrong with this code? Thanks.

```
def player(self, ctx):
        FFMPEG_OPTS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        
        global i
        if i < len(queue_url):
            ctx.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(queue_url[i],  **FFMPEG_OPTS), after= lambda e: self.player_now(ctx))
            i = i+1
    
            
async def player_now(self, ctx):
    global i
    await self.info_now(ctx)
    self.player(ctx)
        
async def info_now(self, ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0x00ff00)
    embed.title = "Playing now" 
    embed.description = queue_title[i] 
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: It would be better if you show us the error you are getting.

Comment: This is, what it shows. "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Main.player_now' was never awaited". I think, the problem is in that ctx.voice_client.play after=lambda. But I don't know, how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

It probably has something to do with the fact that you need to await

```
ctx.voice_client.play
```

```
.play
```

is a coroutine, which means you need to await it. Change it to

```
await ctx.voice_client.play
```

Comment: Yes, that is true, but it wants something like this: "ctx.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(queue_url[i],  **FFMPEG_OPTS), after= lambda e: await self.player_now(ctx))". But this can´t be done, because it shows error  "SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function".